# (C programming) Segfault when combining 2 one-dimensional array into 1 multi-dimensional array

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, segmentation-fault

I am writing a program where I take 2 one dimensional arrays and generate a matrix in its most simplified form Ax=b. 
This part of the function takes in the arrays A and b. A is A[n*n] and b is b[n]. In this section I tried to combine the two arrays so it looks like an actual matrix. 
This code works, however, if n were to be greater than 1023 it would cause a segmentation fault when calling the main function. I was wondering if there is a better way in doing this.   When I tried to use the GDB debugger, it stoped at the line `Y[i][j] = A[k];` so I think this is the problem that requires fixing

```
int linsolve ( int n, double A[], double b[], double x []) {

    double Y[n][n+1];        //Creating multidimensional matrix 
    int k = 0;
    // Turns the two one dimensional array into one multidimensional 
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){        //iterating row
        for (int j=0; j < n; j++){    // per column 

            Y[i][j] = A[k];                // adding from array A to Y 
            k++;
        }
        Y[i][n] = b[i];                 // adding from Array b to Y 
    }
```

Comment: A is a matrix right?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Assuming A has n * n elements
int linsolve ( int n, double A[], double b[], double x []) {
    double **Y = new double *[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Y[i] = new double[n + 1];
    }
    int k = 0;
    // Turns the two one dimensional array into one multidimensional 
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){        //iterating row

        for (int j=0; j < n; j++){    // per column 
            Y[i][j] = A[k++];                // adding from array A to Y 
        }
        Y[i][n] = b[i];                 // adding from Array b to Y 
    }
    // Do something
    // Free up Y before returning
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        delete [] Y[i];
    }
    delete [] Y;
    //Return int here
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but this still encounters a Segfault error unfortunately, could it just be that a matrix cannot handle 1200x1200 ?

Comment: Hi Thanks again for yoru response. I have figure out the problem! Bascially If i were to decalre the Array Y outside the function instead of inside it works.

Comment: It is recommended not to use global variables when you don't need them since debugging(in big projects) becomes extremely difficult. Its about writing good code that matters, but often a solution which runs correctly suffices the need (in small projects).

Comment: k should be outside the loop otherwise all the rows will have the same value as the first row of the matrix

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a Unix/Linux type system.  First find out the stack size by typing

```
ulimit -s
```

This is the stack size in kilobytes.  On my system it is 8Mb.  If you have a 1200x1200 matrix, that will require

```
1200x1201x8 appx 10Mb
```

This is why the program segvs.  You are creating 10Mb array on an 8Mb stack.  The question is, does A or b live on the stack too?  You may be getting a segv because the item you are passing through was created on the stack and is larger than the allocated stack.

To solve it, create the array on the heap as @shirish has suggested.  An alternative to @shirish's technique would be

```
int linsolve ( int n, double A[], double b[], double x []) {
    double **Y = new double *[n];
    double *Ybody = new double[n * (n + 1)];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        Y[i] = &Ybody[i * (n + 1)];
    }

    // Turns the two one dimensional array into one multidimensional 
    int k = 0
    for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
        for (int j=0; j < n; j++){
            Y[i][j] = A[k++]; 
        }
        Y[i][n] = b[i];
    }

    // Do something

    // Free up Y before returning
    delete [] Y;
    delete [] Ybody;
}
```